# Parent state is called twice when transition on child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngresource

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'product/product.html',
    controller: 'products'
}).state('productdetail', {
    url: '/product/:productid',
    templateUrl: 'product_details/productdetails.html',
    resolve: {
           Products: function($stateParams, Product) {
               return Product.fetchList($stateParams.productid);
           }
       },
    controller: 'productDetail'
}).state('category', {
    url: '/category/:category_code',
    templateUrl: 'category/category.html',
    resolve: {
           Categories: function($stateParams, Category) {
               return Category.fetchList($stateParams.category_code);
           }
       },
    controller: 'category'
}).state('category.product', {
    // url: '/category/:category_code',
    templateUrl: 'category/products.html',
    // resolve: {
    //        Categories: function($stateParams, Category) {
    //            return Category.fetchList($stateParams.category_code);
    //        }
    //    },
    // controller: 'category'
})
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

});

in my controller I use :
$state.transitionTo('category.product')
this will load my controller twice first it call http://localhost:3000/category/cat_code
then
http://localhost:3000/category

Comment: Do you have same url and same controller for "category.product" this nested router with its ancestor category?